# What is the equivalent of iOS StackView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a group of `EditTexts` inside a `ConstraintLayout` as shown in the picture below:

[image]

I would like to put them inside something that's equivalent to a StackView in iOS/Xcode Storyboard. Then after that, I would like to set the `Distribution` attribute to something like `Fill Equally`.

How can I do this, NOT in code, but in Android Studio Layout Editor?

**Update: Based on a comment that suggests I should explain what an iOS StackView is, here it is:
Instead of setting constraints for each EditText individually (which would be too tedious), I would like to do what Xcode already offers. That is grouping all of these `EditTexts` in a so-called `'Stack'`. By doing so, I would only have to set the constraint of the `'Stack'` once. Inside the Stack, then I need to describe how each `EditText` is layed out in relation to one another. `Fill Equally distribution` is one way.**

Comment: You should describe what stackview does.  Most android devs won't know what it is.  Describe what the Distibution parameter does as well.  As for doing it in layout editor and not code-  you'll get an answer in xml, because nobody does Android design and layout in the layout editor.

Comment: @GabeSechan Nobody did, because it wasn't available. Now it is. There's a reason why it exists now. As far as describing even more details, this question is for those who already know both platforms.

Comment: It existed for over 8 years. Nobody uses it because xml is faster, more accurate, more efficient, and easily posted to the internet. If you're going to use android learn it

Comment: "If you're going to use android learn it" That's uncalled for.

Comment: If you don't, you'll be unable to ask any questions about layout, or understand any answers. Nobody does android by posting pictures of a gui tool. You need to actually learn the tools on your system

Comment: You don't know the answer, that's OK. But you need to re-train or continue to learn. https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor (7-8 November 2018) No, what you learned 8 years ago is no longer the latest. Stop wasting time posting comment. I post the question here to learn.

Comment: Sure, they put out a minor upgrade.  But the layout editor has been around for a decade.  In the meantime, if you spend time learning that, you won't be learning xml, which is what you'll actually be using on Android.  In fact its what the layout editor outputs- except that its much faster just to write it.

Comment: try this, select all items and choose Distribute horizontally from the menu.

Comment: @GabeSechan You are doing a dis-service by telling future readers the wrong knowledge or at least outdated info. It is clearly stated on Android Developer page "In the Layout Editor, you can quickly build layouts by dragging UI elements into a visual design editor instead of writing the layout XML by hand...The Layout Editor is especially powerful when building a new layout with ConstraintLayout"

Comment: @KevinLe-Khnle Of course they're going to tout their own tool.  YOu're doing yourself a misservice by not listening to expoert advise, or looking at the thousands of questions on layouts on this site, or the thousands of android tutorials, and realizing they ALL use traw xml.  Please note the ContrraintLayout, which does have its uses, is perfectly capable of being used in XML as well.

Answer (score 14):

I think you are searching about the `LinearLayout` which is equivalent to `StackView` in iOS,

`LinearLayout` can have two directions, `horizontal` and `vertical`, and you can select the needed one as your case.

Read about the LinearLayout [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout) in the android documentation, I think this will help.

Comment: I'm interested in using ConstraintLayout, and in only using the AS Layout Editor.

Comment: @KevinLe-Khnle `LinearLayout` is the equivalent one for the StackView not the `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: You can also use, gravity with the linearlayout to set everything, and also that can be used if the screen change from horizontal to vertical

Comment: Yes, I just confirmed that all it requires is nesting the EditTexts in a LinearLayout and then place the LinearLayout inside the outer ConstraintLayout. But you don't have to replace CL with LL in the outer most. I upvoted your answer.